# how to get request header from angular page?

Tags: angular

I am using an external authentication that receives a URL and passes some parameters in the header to enter the already authenticated system.

What I did was make my frontend (angular) an address / login that has the user / password access.

I'm trying to make the angle when entering / login (in the browser) IF I have the headers already skip the login screen, but I can't get the 'request token' as shown in the image, the request token are sent but with 'ActivatedRoute' or 'Router 'I still couldn't get it.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUJYP.png)

Comment: When you say "I can't get it" what steps have you tried to get it?

Comment: I just tried a console.log (router) and console.log (activatedRoute) and found no header information... :(

Comment: So I'm guessing because you've tagged it as Angular you're using HttpClient, assuming you are you need to pass {observe: 'response'} as an argument to your REST service call so that it returns the full response not just the content e.g. `this.httpClient.get('http://endpoint.com/data', {observe: 'response'});`

Comment: Alex, yes I am using HttpClient, but this call that I showed in the image for '/ login' is when I make the same frontend (browser) there is no request for this call made by me, it is made automatically by the angle to return the html from frontend.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by headers on a route, headers come from HTTP requests so they don't exist on your route, they are a property of the HTTP request. When you call /login do it like this `this.httpClient.get(http://xxxxxx/login, {observe: 'response' };

Comment: I mean that the example of the '/ login' I sent is the URL used in the browser to load only the html of the page and not a path in the backend (I just sent just an image to show that the parameters are actually being sent in the header)